# how to mass delete duplicate files in fslint

Tags: duplicate, duplicate-files

recently used fslint it found more than 10000 duplicate files ,

now we don't want to sit and go through all of the files, we tried searching internet but no avail

Wewant to make fslint to keep just one copy of each file and delete all other files at one go , how do we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[better late than never]

I think the answer is in using the 'select' button on the left.

[image]

I selected "all but oldest", and it appeared to behave as expected:

[image]

I could then "eyeball" this selection and delete at will.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use the command line utility findup bundled with the fslint official package. Find it in the installation directory `/usr/share/fslint/fslint`.
Let's say, you want to 'delete duplicates, not merge with links' a home directory:

```
/usr/share/fslint/fslint/findup -d /home/chemist
```

Simply read the manual (?!)

```
Usage: findup [[[-t [-m|-d]] | [--summary]] [-r] [-f] paths(s) ...]

 If no path(s) specified then the current directory is assumed.

 When -m is specified any found duplicates will be merged (using hardlinks).
 When -d is specified any found duplicates will be deleted (leaving just 1).
 When -t is specfied, only report what -m or -d would do.
 When --summary is specified change output format to include file sizes.
 You can also pipe this summary format to /usr/share/fslint/fslint/fstool/dupwaste
 to get a total of the wastage due to duplicates.
```

For more information, see the [FsLint Official Documentation](http://booki.flossmanuals.net/fslint/index)
FsLint homepage: http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/

[image: FsLint GUI]

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question , I’m sorry I unable to comprehend your answer , I was looking for something like delete all duplicate files at once , instead hitting delete button to each and everyone

Comment: The answer is: use the command line tool `findup` instead of the graphical user interface. `findup -d /path/to/folder` will delete all duplicates in the specified folder. rtfm

Comment: So it’s impossible to do it in gui fslint nright?

Comment: I get findup not found error when I use it in terminal

Comment: Please read the doc from provided link. You'll find all answers you need.

Comment: I think it’s finddup , it worked for me. And findup does not exist